# Spinner / ListView wont refresh after DataBase insert

Tags: android, listview

Im new to Android Developement and currently working on my first app that should give me the time between first time clicking a button and second time clicking the button and save it to a currently selected customer.(I know there are already tons of those applications out there, but since im still learning and want an app that can be usefull for myself i decided to try [​IMG])

To the problem:

When my app starts, in the main activity i call a method, that requests all my "customers" from the database and stores them in a list.
This list i use to display the customers in a ListView and a spinner.
The spinner is also created in the main activity onCreate(). So after i get the data from the database i want to fill the spinner with this data. But it doesnt work, to show the data when starting the app.

What doesnt work either:

When adding a new customer in the app, the customer is saved to the database. 
then i have to open my ListView(Button: Kundenübersicht) two times till the new customers is displayed. After that, the data is also visible in the spinner.

Heres my code:

MainActivity(ZeitErfassen)

```
public class ZeitErfassen extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static LinkedList<Kunde> kunden = new LinkedList<Kunde>();
    boolean running = false;
    long startTime,endTime,totalTime;

    private SharedPreferences app_preferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private TextView displayTime;
    public Button startEndButton;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private Spinner spinner;
    public static Kunde selectedCustomer;
    private static int numberOfCustomers = -1;
    static final int AddCustomer_REQUEST = 1; // REQUEST CODE FOR CALLING list after update




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zeit_erfassen);
        //Einstellungen laden
        app_preferences =  getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        startTime= app_preferences.getLong("startTime", 0);
        endTime = app_preferences.getLong("endTime", 0);
        running = app_preferences.getBoolean("running", false);
        displayTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.zeit_bei_Kunde);
        displayTime.setText((CharSequence) app_preferences.getString("zeitAnzeige", "Zeit bei Kunde"));
        startEndButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start_Timer);
        startEndButton.setText((CharSequence) app_preferences.getString("timerButton", "Start Timer"));
        editor = app_preferences.edit();
        editor.commit();
    }


    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        editor.putLong("startTime", startTime);
        editor.putString("zeitAnzeige", (String) displayTime.getText());
        editor.putString("timerButton", (String) startEndButton.getText());
        editor.putLong("endTime", endTime);
        editor.putLong("totalTime", totalTime);
        editor.putBoolean("running", app_preferences.getBoolean("running", false));
        editor.commit();
        this.finish();
    }


    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        DatabaseHelper.customerFromDatabaseToList(this);
        createDropDown();
        numberOfCustomers= kunden.size();
    }
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        DatabaseHelper.customerFromDatabaseToList(this);
        createDropDown();
        numberOfCustomers = kunden.size();
    }


    public void startTimer(View view) {
        editor = app_preferences.edit();

        if(running == false) {
            startTime = getTime();
            running = true;
            editor.putLong("startTime", startTime);
            startEndButton.setText("End Timer");
            displayTime.setText("Zeitstoppung läuft");
            editor.putString("zeitAnzeige", (String) displayTime.getText());
            editor.putString("timerButton", (String) startEndButton.getText());
            editor.putBoolean("running", true);
            editor.commit();

        } else {
            setSelectedCustomer();
            endTime = getTime();
            editor.putLong("endTime",endTime);
            totalTime = endTime - startTime;
            editor.putLong("totalTime", totalTime);
            displayTime.setText(formatTime(totalTime));
            editor.putString("zeitAnzeige", (String) displayTime.getText());
            startEndButton.setText("Start Timer");
            editor.putString("timerButton", (String) startEndButton.getText());
            running = false;
            editor.putBoolean("running", false);
            editor.commit();
            DatabaseHelper.timeToDatabase(String.valueOf(selectedCustomer.getId()),formatTime(totalTime),this);
        //    selectedCustomer.saveTimeToCustomer(selectedCustomer, formatTimeForCustomer(totalTime));

        }
    }

    public String formatTime(Long totalTime) {
        int hours   = (int) ((totalTime / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
        int minutes = (int) ((totalTime / (1000*60)) % 60);
        int seconds = (int) (totalTime / 1000) % 60;

        String time = (String.valueOf(hours) + ":" + String.valueOf(minutes) + ":" + String.valueOf(seconds));
        return time;
    }

    public String formatTimeForCustomer(Long totalTime) {
        StringBuilder time = new StringBuilder();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year    = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month   = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day     = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        time.append((String.valueOf(year) + "." + String.valueOf(month) + "." + String.valueOf(day))).append(formatTime(totalTime));
        return time.toString();
    }

    public void  neuerKunde(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddKunde.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, AddCustomer_REQUEST);
    }
    public void kundenÜbersicht(View view) {
    //    setSelectedCustomer();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayCustomer.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public long getTime() {
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return millis;
    }

    public void setSelectedCustomer() {
        if(kunden.size() > 0) {
            if (spinner.getSelectedItem().toString() != null) {
                String tempCustomer = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                for (Kunde k : kunden) {
                    if (k.getName().equals(tempCustomer)) {
                        selectedCustomer = k;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void createDropDown() {
            if (kunden.size() > 0) {
                spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.chooseCustomer);
                // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, DisplayCustomer.namesOfCustomers());

                // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                // Apply the adapter to the spinner
                spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == AddCustomer_REQUEST) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                DatabaseHelper.customerFromDatabaseToList(getApplicationContext());
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Write your code if there's no result
            }
        }
    }//onActivityResult
}
```

DatabaseHelper Class

```
public class DatabaseHelper {
    public static RequestQueue requestQueue;
    public static final String host = "http://192.168.150.238/";
    public static final String insertUrl = host+"insertCustomer.php";
    public static final String showUrl = host+"showCustomer.php";
    public static final String insertTimeUrl = host+"insertTime.php";
    public static final String showTimeUrl = host+"showTimes.php";

    public static void customerFromDatabaseToList(final Context context)  {
        //Display customer from database
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        final ArrayList<String> customerNames = new ArrayList<>();
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, showUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray customers = response.getJSONArray("customers");
                    if(customers.length() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < customers.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject customer = customers.getJSONObject(i);
                            String customerName = customer.getString("cus_name");
                            String customerAddress = customer.getString("cus_address");
                            int customerID = Integer.valueOf(customer.getString("cus_id"));
                            if (customerName != null && customerAddress != null) {
                                try {
                                    Kunde k = new Kunde(customerName, customerAddress, customerID);
                                    if (!listContainsObject(k)) {
                                        ZeitErfassen.kunden.add(k);
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Fehler in customerFromDatabaseToListn!Code:X1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(context,"Fehler in customerFromDatabaseToListn!Code:X2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Fehler bei holen der Daten!Code:X3",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Fehler beim holen der Daten!Code:X4",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    public static boolean listContainsObject(Kunde cust) {
        for(Kunde k : ZeitErfassen.kunden) {
            if((k.getId() >0 )&& (k.getId() == cust.getId())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void timeToDatabase(final String customer_id, final String time_value, final Context context) {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, DatabaseHelper.insertTimeUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Fehler beim holen der Daten!Code:X5",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String,String>();
                parameters.put("customerid",customer_id);
                parameters.put("timevalue",time_value);
                return parameters;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(request);
    };

    public static ArrayList<String> timesFromDataBaseToList(final Context context,final int customer_id) {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        final String cus_id = String.valueOf(customer_id) ;
        final ArrayList<String> customerTimes = new ArrayList<>();

        StringRequest jsonObjectRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, showTimeUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                    JSONArray times = object.getJSONArray("customertimes");
                    if (times.length() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < times.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = times.getJSONObject(i);
                            String timeValue = jsonObject.getString("time_value");
                            if (timeValue != null) {
                                customerTimes.add(timeValue);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Fehler beim holen der Daten!Code:X6",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Fehler beim Holen der Zeiten, keine Verbindung zur Datenbank!Code: X7",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
        }){
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String,String>();
                parameters.put("cus_id",cus_id);
                return parameters;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        return customerTimes;
    };
}
```

DisplayCustomers / Where I Display my Customers in a List

```
public class DisplayCustomer extends AppCompatActivity {
    CustomerAdapter customerAdapter;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> adapterCustomerView;
    private ListView listCustomerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_customer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        ArrayList<Kunde> customerList = getCustomerObjects();
        customerAdapter = new CustomerAdapter(this,customerList);
        listCustomerView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_View_Customers);
        //  adapterCustomerView = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, namesOfCustomers());
        listCustomerView.setAdapter(customerAdapter);
        openCustomerDetails();
    }


    public static ArrayList<String> namesOfCustomers() {
        ArrayList<String> customerNames = new ArrayList<>();
        if(ZeitErfassen.kunden.size() > 0 ) {
            for (Kunde k : ZeitErfassen.kunden) {
                customerNames.add(k.getName());
            }
        }
        return customerNames;
    }


    public static ArrayList<Kunde> getCustomerObjects() {
        ArrayList<Kunde> customerList = new ArrayList<>();
        if(ZeitErfassen.kunden.size() > 0 ) {
            for (Kunde k : ZeitErfassen.kunden) {
                customerList.add(k);
            }
        }
        return customerList;
    }


    public void openCustomerDetails() {
        listCustomerView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Kunde kunde = new Kunde();
                kunde = (Kunde)listCustomerView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayCustomer.this, DisplayDetailedCustomer.class);
                intent.putExtra("selectedCustomerObject",(Parcelable)kunde);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

AddKunde / Class for adding customer

```
public class AddKunde extends AppCompatActivity {

    public RequestQueue requestQueue;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_kunde);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }



    public void addKunde(View view) throws Exception {
        try {
            EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.customerName);
            String name = nameField.getText().toString();
            EditText addressField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressField);
            String address = addressField.getText().toString();
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){
                nameField.setError("Ungültiger Name!");
                return;
            } else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(address)){
                addressField.setError("Ungültige Adresse");
                return;
            } else {
                try {
                    customerToDatabase(name, address);
                    Kunde customer = new Kunde(name, address);
                    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                    returnIntent.putExtra("kunde",customer);
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                } catch (VolleyError e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Fehler: Keine Verbindung zur Datenbank!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Fehler in addKunde!");
        }
        finish();
    }



        public void customerToDatabase(final String name, final String address) {
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, DatabaseHelper.insertUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                   Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String,String>();
                    parameters.put("customername",name);
                    parameters.put("customeraddress",address);
                    return parameters;
                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(request);
        };
}
```